# Liquibase Grails database migrations

Tags: database, grails, migration

I followed the excellent tutorial on 
http://www.jakusys.de/blog/2008/09/grails-and-liquibase-how-to-use/

in regard to my dev database on local machine where grails is installed. All went well.

Now I want to deploy grails war to remote website where I setup mysql on remote server.

But I am at loss now. How do I apply the command:
grails migrate

so that the now the remote database has the DATABASECHANGELOG table.

In the database there is some production data that I will manually copy from my local mysql to fresh install of remote mysql database while most of other tables are fresh and have no data. I am waiting for reply to this question to make sure I don't mess up something before actually launch my grails application on remote production  server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can migrate a remote DB from your computer, using `grails.env` variable, like:

```
grails migrate -Dgrails.env=production
```

Comment: for prod just do `grails prod migrate` - using the grails.env variable is only needed for custom environments

Comment: I am not sure how grails prod migrate would work because in my DataSource.groovy both development and production databases are the same db in the local machine. So how I make grails prod migrate access the remote db located around the globe somewhere else? The production setting are intended to create a war that I can then eitehr deploy under locally running tomcat or copy to remote server in which case it would talk to remote mysql db on the server.

Comment: Put into `DataSource.groovy` an explicit IP or domain name of DB server for production environment, and it will. Unless you deploy to multiple sites, that will work. If you do, you still can create a separate Grails environment just for upgrade purpose.