# Grails DataSource for remote MYSQL database access and migrations

Tags: mysql, database, grails, migration

Is it possible for locally running grails application to access and update remote MySQL db?
Assume the remote server is linux on which tomcat, MySQL are installed in the usual places.
Assume remote URL is accessed as tom@189.124.24.249. So grails needs to access the db as the user 'tom' or does it need to be the root user or mysql user??? Does the password of user tom need to be specified in the DataSource.groovy? In MYSQL the db test_db is configured to be accessed with user name 'guru' and password 'secret'.

If the same grails application is also running on the remote server accessing that remote db, a locally running instance of grails application accessing the same remote db should not cause any problems??

Assume the remote db name is test_db.

I need this also in context with liquibase grails plugin and database migrations. I need to run grails migrate command against the remote db to synchronize it with local db.

A side question: how do I synchronize local db in which table data is already populated to remote fresh newly created db with no data? This seems to fall under the domain of db content migrations which is not covered by the grails plugin as far as I know. I would like to know what would be the correct approach to this in the context of a grails application.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set the proper credentials in the Datasource.groovy and it all should work fine. We are running our app in a production environment and the database server is on a different box.

I dont think that two applications accessing the database server should be a problem.

Can't help with the side question... sorry

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it's mostly a duplicate of [Liquibase Grails database migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398223/liquibase-grails-database-migrations/4400077)

For side question: after Grails migrates structure, `mysqldump` or whatever backup/restore procedure should work.